# Laravel 4.2 Date Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

How do I validate a date in such a way that it only accepts today and any date older than today? I know `before:today` accepts older dates while `after:today` accepts dates starting tomorrow on-wards.

```
 $rules = [
    'start_at'      => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:yesterday',
    'end_at'        => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:start_at',
];
```

I want to be able to start a task today and end today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, you want the `end_at` to on the same date or after `start_at` but not before `start_at`.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'start_at'  => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:yesterday',
            'end_at'    => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:' . \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->start_date)->subDay()->toDateString(),
        ];
    }
```

What I have done so far, The `end_at` need to be relevant with the `start_at` (same or after the `start_at`).

1. I'm using Carbon to convert start_at into date.
2. Subtract date by 1 day.
3. Convert it back to string according to the `strtotime` PHP function.

Comment: Not really. I want to set my start date to be either today, tomorrow or any date after today (i.e next week, next month etc). It's not compulsory for it to start today. I have a problem on the end date. I want to set the end date to be flexible. I can decide to start a task today and end it the same day, or start a task today and end it a future date. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean  you want the `end_at` to on the same date or after `start_at` but not before `start_at`?

Comment: Yes. Logically the end date cannot be before the start date, but can be the same date as start date or a date in the future

Comment: @Richie I just revised my answer. I hope It helps you through.